# Opening and closing GUI's using class concept

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, tkinter

I basically have two python scripts Test_A and Test_B. Both these are tkinter based GUIs. I am trying to open one GUI using another. I have a button in each of the GUI which opens the other and the function which corresponds to the button destroys the current GUI. Sadly, what happens is I am unable to destroy the TK() object created using one class in another. Is there any way to circumvent this issue ? For example, when I run Test_A.py and click "***open GUI 2 button***" the second GUI opens, now when I click the "***Open GUI 1 button***" the first does not open and it says NameError: name “window2” is not defined.

*My two scripts are as follows:*

```
from tkinter import *
from Test_B import *


class Test_A_class(Frame):

    def F1(self):
        Window1.destroy()
        Window2 = Tk()
        Tool = Test_B_class(Window2)
        Window2.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Button = Button(self, command=self.F1, text="Open GUI 2", width=15)
        self.Button.pack()        

    def __init__(self, initial):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Window1 = Tk()
    Tool = Test_A_class(Window1)
    Window1.mainloop()
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
from tkinter import *
from Test_A import *


class Test_B_class(Frame):

    def F2(self):
        Window2.destroy()
        Window1 = Tk()
        Tool = Test_A_class(Window1)
        Window1.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Button = Button(self, command=self.F2, text="Open GUI 1", width=15)
        self.Button.pack()        

    def __init__(self, initial):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    Window2 = Tk()
    Tool = Test_B_class(Window2)
    Window2.mainloop()
```

The error is as follows:

```
Window2.destroy()
NameError: name 'Window2' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?

Comment: It says "Window 2" is undefined !. I do understand that it is because window 2 is defined in Test_A_class.

Comment: "Window 2" or "Window2"? When asking technical questions it's important to be precise. You should [edit] your question and add the actual error and stacktrace.

Comment: didn’t know that. Now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, I have found the solution. What I have done now is, I have declared the Tk() variables inside the "____init____" method of the respective classes. This enables me to avoid giving an argument to the class whenever it is executed. Next, I used import function after I destroy the current GUI to invoke the other class. Whenever a new class is invoked its ____init____ function automatically declares the Tk(). Previously the Windows were being declared outside the class and hence they had no scope within the class. Hope this helps some people. I have posted the updated code here. Let me know if we can improve this further.

```
from tkinter import *
from Test_B import *


class Test_A_class(Frame):

    def F1(self):
        self.Window1.destroy()
        import Test_B
        Tool = Test_B.Test_B_class()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Button = Button(self, command=self.F1, text="Open GUI 2", width=15)
        self.Button.pack()        

    def __init__(self):
        self.Window1 = Tk()
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tool = Test_A_class()
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx

```
from tkinter import *
from Test_A import *


class Test_B_class(Frame):

    def F2(self):
        self.Window2.destroy()
        import Test_A
        Tool = Test_A.Test_A_class()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Button = Button(self, command=self.F2, text="Open GUI 1", width=15)
        self.Button.pack()        

    def __init__(self):
        self.Window2 = Tk()
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    Tool = Test_B_class()
```